# how to use CPLEX write this piecewise function

Tags: cplex, opl

```
 forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i<=6 || i==10) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==1)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
  forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i<=9 || i>=7) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==2)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
  forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i>=11) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==3)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlacc.png)
thank you for your answer

> i divided this piecewise function into three functions ,but the model error... so i guess maybe the mistake of this piecewise function

Comment: In ´ i<=9 || i>=7´ the || Looks Strange don’t you mean && ?

Answer (score 0):

In ´ i<=9 || i>=7´ the || Looks Strange don’t you mean && ?

```
range pr=1..10;
range Wh=1..3;
range DC=1..2;
range Fa=1..3;
range ra=1..3;

dvar int Q2[pr][Wh][DC];
dvar int Qf2[Fa][Wh][DC][ra];
subject to
{


forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i<=6 || i==10) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==1)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
  forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i<=9 && i>=7) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==2)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
  forall (i in pr, m in Wh, k in DC)
    sum(i in pr:i>=11) Q2[i][m][k] == sum(r in ra,f in Fa:f==3)Qf2[f][m][k][r];
  }
```

works fine